# As soon as I execute "screen", it tells me "cannot exec rwar: no such file or directory"

Tags: gnu-screen

There has to be something I'm misunderstanding. I can simply start "screen" on another Linux box and it opens up just fine, but when I try starting "screen" on my Linux box, it seems as though it's trying to execute a command or something. Screen then terminates after it gives me this error message on the bottom of the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `screen` installed on your system ?

Comment: if not, then assuming you have `apt-get`, use: `sudo apt-get install screen`

Comment: Yeah, it's installed. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Look for the command name in your `$HOME/.screenrc`, or possibly in `/etc/screenrc`.

Comment: Neither one of these files exist. I did a find / -name "screenrc" earlier and didn't find anything. Just tried it again just to be sure though.

Comment: Can you post exact command lines that demonstrate the problem?